# terrain patch texture dimensions

Tags: modeling, texturing

Say, I have made a terrain patch of dimensions MxN, what rules of thumb do there exist to determine the dimension of the texture WxH, used to texture the terrain patch? From what I understand W and H can be arbitrary, but a low-resolution texture may not look good at all, a too high resolution texture leads to wastage (since more mip-maps need to be generated for the patch to look good when the patch is far away from the camera, I believe). Should I choose W, H from M, N, or should I choose M, N from W, H?

Comment: if you use a tileable texture, you don't even have to make a choice, you just do it. it all tiles out seamlessly, everyone's happy.

Comment: @VinceScalia I meant the texture used for texture painting the terrain patch.